# Big CMS database Structure

Tags: database, algorithm, data-structures, structure

I'm working on big cms, there is 2 levels: admins, clients.

here is my database structure

**table name:** `app_Clients`

**columns:**

```
ID(INT A_I) 

site_code(VARCHAR) 

database_id(INT) - *many-to-many relationship with app_Databases table*

license_id(INT) - *many-to-many relationship with app_Licenses table (not important for the problem)*
```

**talbe name:** `app_Databases`

**columns:**

```
ID(INT A_I) 

database_user(VARCHAR)

database_name(VARCHAR)

database_password(VARCHAR)
```

[image: IMAGE to describe the situation]

everything is ok, but what if i added a new model to the system that required new table or new column
on the client database?

It makes no sense that I would have to go through a every database of clients and change/edit the Structure.

**Does anyone have an idea for a different solution?**

Comment: some ideas: store all data in a 'single database' and filter by login, maybe horizontally partitioning per client. look into stuff like http://michaelbaylon.wordpress.com/2010/10/08/agile-database-development-101/, create deployment scripts that will automate the process. consider migrating client data to a new database rather than altering the working schema.